# Как создать процесс демон на node.js

Tags: node.js

Как создать процесс-демон на node.js, который будет принимать данные от другого процесса и отвечать ему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучший демон менеджер на мой субъективный взгляд pm2 попробуйте

[pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Сами данные уже можете гонять между ними как угодно, хоть сокеты, хоть json-ы

Comment: Спасибо)) полезно )

Comment: Спасибо.. Но как это сделать вручную.

Comment: Пожалуйста по подробнее проблему или задачу опишите, а то я наверное думаю про другое

Comment: @BogdanDerevyaga пожалуйста по подробнее про задачу

Comment: Я предпочитаю [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), pm2 всё же больше для контроля за сервером предназначен, в боевых условиях это лишняя нагрузка

Comment: Нужно создать сервер который будет делать манипуляцию с данными и несколько клиентов. Клиенты должны быть независимыми от сервера. Но с возможностью поднять, убить сервер, передать эму данные и получить данные.

Comment: @BogdanDerevyaga DNS сервер возьмите. Или mysql. Они это умеют, как и большинство серверов.

Comment: @BogdanDerevyaga сервер соответственно на node? А клиенты на чем?

Comment: @BogdanDerevyaga могу порекомендовать посмотреть Socket.IO как пример использования есть статья на хабре называется "Создаем чат на Node.js и Socket.IO"

Comment: Клиент на node.js console line, другой на expres